# Can not resolve symbol CreateTodoInput

Tags: android, aws-amplify

In order to build an Android app using AWS Amplify CLI, I followed the steps in:

> https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start?ref=amplify-android-btn

However, I must be missing something.

```
Generated GraphQL operations successfully and saved at app\src\main\graphql\com\amazonaws\amplify\generated\graphql     
√ All resources are updated in the cloud
```

After following Step 5: Integrate into your app, I get:

```
cannot resolve symbol CreateTodoInput
```

None of those classes can be found: CreateTodoInput, CreateTodoMutation. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshing the gradle and updating the version from 9 to 10 seemed to do the trick:

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.10.0'
```