# Android Studio Error : Cannot resolve symbol CreateTodoInput and CreateTodoMutation

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio, aws-amplify

I am trying to build an Android app using AWS Amplify CLI.

I am following [the AWS documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start?ref=amplify-android-btn). However, I am getting this error, in Android Studio:

> Cannot resolve symbol CreateTodoInput and CreateTodoMutation

I have pasted all the dependencies as present in the documentation in my app and project Gradle files.

I found a similar question ([Can not resolve symbol CreateTodoInput](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54116742/695787)), but the answer provided doesn't resolve my issue.

My entire code is in `MainActivity.java`:

```java
package com.example.testamplify;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.mobile.config.AWSConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.appsync.AWSAppSyncClient;
import com.apollographql.apollo.GraphQLCall;
import com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloException;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AWSAppSyncClient mAWSAppSyncClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAWSAppSyncClient = AWSAppSyncClient.builder()
            .context(getApplicationContext())
            .awsConfiguration(new AWSConfiguration(getApplicationContext()))
            .build();
        runMutation();
    }

    public void runMutation() {
        CreateTodoInput createTodoInput = CreateTodoInput.builder()
            .name("Use AppSync")
            .description("Realtime and Offline")
            .build();
        mAWSAppSyncClient
            .mutate(CreateTodoMutation.builder()
                .input(createTodoInput).build()
            )
            .enqueue(mutationCallback);
    }

    private GraphQLCall.Callback<CreateTodoMutation.Data> mutationCallback =
        new GraphQLCall.Callback<CreateTodoMutation.Data>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<CreateTodoMutation.Data> response) {
                Log.i("Results", "Added Todo");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.toString());
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncing my project with gradle files resolved the issue !!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as I'm new and experimenting with this too. I think CreateTodo is a type of variable. Download this example of an android app provided by AWS, found [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-appsync-events-starter-android). Open the ListEventsActivity, on line 77. You will see this same code, hope it helps you understand, it helped me.

Comment: Thanks Mago Lups - I checked the ListEventsActivity, on line 77 - `private GraphQLCall.Callback<ListEventsQuery.Data> eventsCallback = new GraphQLCall.Callback<ListEventsQuery.Data>() { `   . But I didn't get what changes do I need to make to my code so that my issue would be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Retry the tutorial again, and when you use `amplify add api`, after amplify push.

It'll ask the follow `Do you want to generate code for your newly created GraphQL API`. At first i choose no, and the folder graphql was not generated.

So, when the prompt ask

> `Do you want to generate code for your newly created GraphQL API`

You have to answer yes and configure with the default values.

At least, that was wrong wit me, give it a try.